# Pattern rule expansion doubht in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have rules in Makefile similar to the following.

```
BOARDS := B1 B2 B3 B4
```

Rule 1:

```
.PHONY: $(BOARDS)
$(BOARDS): %: baisc_% debug_%
```

Rule 2:

```
SYSTEM_BOARDS = $(foreach board,$(BOARDS),basic_$(board))
.PHONY: $(SYSTEM_BOARDS)
$(SYSTEM_BOARDS):basic_%: packages_%
```

I think Rule 1 is expanded as following. Please correct me if I am worng.

```
B1: basic_B1 debug_B1

B2: basic_B2 debug_B2

B3: basic_B3 debug_B3

B4: basic_B4 debug_B4
```

Can you help to understand how Rule 2 will be expanded.

Comment: Run `make -pR` and find out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My doubt here is, the value of % in "Rule 1" will be same as "Rule 2". What is the meaning, if we define pattern between Double-Colon, i.e usage of ":%:" and ":basic_%" in Rule 1 and Rule 2.

Comment: If you're asking about static pattern rules, [here's](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) the page in the make manual.